# Should I extract ReactJs code to other files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I would like to ask you guys if I should extract React code to other files.
As our components grow, we get a lot of specific code in the main .js file. How do you deal with this?

I myself separated what I guess (may be wrong/ actually I'm beggening with React and don't know exactly if it's true) are the main parts of a component's code. I would say then:
- imports
- state management 
- handlers
- conditional rendering 
- the componet's body 
- styling

I usually extract the styles to another .js file (not using css for now), and it's pretty cool, but what about handlers, state management and conditonal rendering?

I gotta say, I'm tempted to do that! hahahahaha
I've been working with Rails for a while and we do this kind of thing SOOO MUUUCH there.

Answer (score 1):

OfCourse, you can split your code by Webpack refer [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)

Comment: Thanks! I asked because I was a little afraid of being nonstandard